# Not able to install node@10 on mac M1 chip device

Tags: python, node.js, macos, apple-m1

### System

[image]

I have a project which requires node@10 to run. I used https://brew.sh to install node@10.

I used the below command to install node@10

```js
brew install --build-from-source node@10
```

It was not able to install and i got the following error.

```js
./configure: line 3: exec: python: not found
```

I installed python using brew.

```js
brew install python
```

The above command installed python3, so i created alias for python

```js
alias python=python3
```

[image]

So, python is working. I  again tried `brew install --build-from-source node@10` and still getting
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment so I'll try to phrase this as an answer:

Chances are there is a messed up symlink somewhere

1. Usually you can use `brew info python` to troubleshoot your python install with homebrew installs.
2. Also use `which python` at the terminal to see the actual path to the python executable.

Comment: Output of `which python -> python: aliased to python3`

Comment: Output of `which python3 -> /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Output if `brew info python` -> https://gist.github.com/rahul-adpushup/4e567cf0fef4676032151709c2ba505c

Comment: i think your issue is because you aliased it instead of setting the path

Comment: Try pyenv: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on MacOS 13.0.1. The only solution worked for me is, downloading node 10.x.x package from https://nodejs.org/en/download/